# C++ concat const char with char

Tags: c++, c

i have defined a value using

```
extern char WEBSRV_ADMIN_ID[31];    char WEBSRV_ADMIN_ID[31]=   "admin";
```

then i want to use the username in a char statement into sql as

```
const char *pSQL[1];
pSQL[1] = "update websrv_config set admin_id='" + WEBSRV_ADMIN_ID + "'";
```

but it seems that there is an error

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [36]’ and ‘char [31]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

how can i overcome it?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? Also, beware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It could cause [serious problems](http://xkcd.com/327/) if you're not careful about which strings you include directly in a query; try to use parameterised queries wherever possible.

Comment: Also, the first element of the array is `pSQL[0]`, not `[1]`, although I've no idea why you's want to use a single-element array at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in C++, use `std::string`. It handles `+` will work as you want it to.

In C, allocate a buffer big enough to contain the whole query and fill it part-by-part using `strncat`.